# Resolving nullable fields with directives

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm developing a GraphQL Directive named `bind` which can be used on fields to resolve into another values.

```
# This is a simplification of the actual definitions

directive @bind(value: String) on INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION | FIELD_DEFINITION

input Request {
  expr: String! @bind(value: "/v1.0/std/expr")
}

type Response {
  message: String
}

type Query {
  hello(request: Request): Response
}
```

It works well if `expr` is a non-null string. I want my directive to be invoked even if `expr` is null.

Would you please tell me how?

Comment: Are you saying you want to force a non-null string to resolve to a null without an error using your directive?

Comment: @DanielRearden I mean if `expr` is a NULL string or not, the directive always get invoked.

Comment: Oh, just noticed that's an input object type. Hmm.